# How can I make the page scroll to an element?

Tags: javascript

I would like to scroll to an element (make it visible for user) even if the element is on the bottom of the page.

I tried

```
document.getElementById('idOfLink').focus();
```

but if the element is on the bottom of a very long page its not visible to the user.

Comment: In jQuery, it's easy to scroll to the offset of any element: `$(window).scrollTop($('#idOfLink').offset().top);`

Comment: @mblase75: it's easier and more robust with plain DOM methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible methods, each suitable in different scenarios:

You can use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView), which will scroll the element into view but will not add save the "state" for when the user presses the back button:

```
document.getElementById('idOfLink').scrollIntoView();
```

If you want back button support, you will need to modify `window.location.hash`:

```
window.location.hash = 'idOfLink';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hash tag as it was originally intended:

```
window.location.hash = "idOfLink"
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfBre/)